# Mega-Menu dropdown doesn't display on hover?

Tags: jquery, magento, drop-down-menu, jquery-hover, megamenu

I am using Magento 1.9x with Ultimo Theme
There is a small issue with my mega-menu display on hover.

- Dropdown Menu on hover displays fine [here](http://styroshop.com/products)
- But menu doesn't display on hover when I am at this [page](https://www.styroshop.com/holiday-bundles)

Can you please help and propose a solution? Please guide which html/css fiels to edit as I am very new to Web development.

Comment: check browser console for js error

Comment: working on both page for me.

Comment: It's have been working at my end perfect no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed, a product variation was named as `"Product Variation"` the inverted commas were causing a javascript error. Renaming the variation to `'Product Variation'` solved my issue.